# Access subdomain on local machine in PHP

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have PHP source code of http://www.sitename.com. I can access it by using sub domain http://www.demo.sitename.com . I have copied all source code from live and stored it on my local machine (e.g. 192.168.15.24).

On local machine WAMP 2.0 is installed.

I have tried to run as following way, but those are wrong.
1. http://192.168.15.24/sitename/demo
2. http://demo.192.168.15.24/sitename/

How can I run the page http://www.demo.sitename.com from my local machine’s IP?

Comment: It is impossible to figure out without some basic information: what webserver are you using in your local machine and how is it configured?

Comment: Why are they wrong? What's not working?

Comment: As i mention, i have source code of http://www.sitename.com. I placed that code on my local machine (192.168.15.24). Now, i can access from my local machine as http://192.168.15.24/sitename properly. <br> On live i got output for http://www.demo1.sitename.com, http://www.demon.sitename.com.  If i want to access from my local machine. How can i access it?

Answer (score 2):

A quick hack that might help:

Open `%windir%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts` e.g. `C:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts` in a text editor like notepad. Add a line with `192.168.15.24 www.demo.sitename.com`. Now visiting www.demo.sitename.com will connect to your LAN IP instead.